# Html image from http site not displayed on my https site in Chrome after moving to VPS

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, https

I moved to VPS server from virtual hosting. My site works through https. But it loads an image (latex formula) over http. Before moving to VPS my site was loading http images without problems. But after moving to VPS Chrome browser stopped displaying images got by http. Firefox displays them. What changes should I make to VPS server configuration so that it would display http images in Chrome?

view_topic.php

```
echo '<img align="middle" src="http://fx.ifz.ru/tex2.php?d=120&i=%24%24' . rawurlencode("\\pi") . '%24%24">'; // for clarity i changed $array[$i] to "\\pi". A greek letter pi should be displayed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the UTF8 character set metadata to your head element, like so:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that google chrome updated itself and new version doesn't allow for http requests from within https.